# Where should I find electrolytic capacitor ageing data

Tags: dataset, predictive-modeling, data, data-science-model, prediction

I am trying to get a dataset of Electrolytic capacitors ageing and I am not being able to find one that shows the ripple current and the voltage in order to calculate its Equivalent Series Resistance (a nice parameter to check its degradation).

I have look on the typical sites (kaggle, dataworld...) but I found none.

May someone recomend me a site?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Imho it's unlikely that you would find this kind of very specific data on generalist websites, you should probably for expert sources  like research papers. If you want you can try asking on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/, maybe you're going to be lucky.

Comment: Research papers are my main lead but it is unlikely that the database used is shared.

Comment: if experts don't share their data, non-experts probably don't have it. Sorry!